# How to get Sharepoint image in relative url format

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I have an SPListItem that I return a full image url:

`http://sharepointsite.com/images/bob's picture.jpg`

I return this url by calling this:

`splistitem.File.ServerRelativeUrl`

I want to be able to turn this url into this:

`http://sharepointsite.com/images/bob%27s%20picture.jpg`

but if I encode the full URL it will replace the `/` which i dont want.  I want to be able to just get the ending image file and UrlEncode that, how would I go about solving this progmmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var url = "http://sharepointsite.com/images/bob's picture.jpg";
 var basePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(url);
 var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);
 var finalPath = basePath + "\\" + Uri.EscapeDataString(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by simply calling `splistitem.File[SPBuiltInFieldId.EncodedAbsUrl]` - it won't replace the forward-slashes. And then you can pass it to `System.IO.Path.GetFileName` if you want only the filename.

By the way, shouldn't ServerRelativeUrl return /images/bob's picture.jpg?